# connect a local repo to a new branch on a remote repo

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I have a remote GitLab repo `my-project` that contains 2 branches `master` and `dev`. And I have a directory on my local machine named also `my-project` that I was developing some code in it and it has more or less the same structure as the remote repo. What I want to do is:

1. initialise the directory as a git repo (which I already did)
2. connect the initialised local repo somehow to the remote one.
3. Then create a branch based on the structure of the `master` branch of the remote repo (without losing any files on the local repo).
4. finally, push the code in the local repo to the newly created branch in the new repo.

what I have done so far is:

```
cd my-project
git init
git fetch
git checkout -b new_dev_branch
git add .
git commit -m "first trial"
git remote add origin path/to/remote/gitlab/my-project.git
git push -u origin new_dev_branch
```

But the problem is that it didn't create the branch with the structure of the master as I wanted in step 3.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TL;DR

You've created a new *root commit* in your new repository.  That's not what you wanted.  You need a different (non-root) commit.

[Sajib Khan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69049401/1256452), suggesting merging or cherry-picking, is likely to hit stumbling blocks (depending on your specific Git version, but since you mention GitLab, you will have a Git version that is newer than 2.9).

You can fix this in several ways.  Read the "long" section below to see all of them, and why this summary should be correct (note that I can't actually *test* it).  Here is the summary of the "fix things" command sequence, which is your shortest path forward from where you are right now:

```
git push --delete origin new_dev_branch
git branch -m error
git fetch
git switch -c new_dev_branch --no-track dev
git restore --source error -SW -- .
git commit
```

(put in a good commit message here!)

```
git push -u origin new_dev_branch
```

I'm assuming you have Git 2.23 or later; if not, see below.

## Long

You're starting from the wrong idea.  You are thinking that Git stores files, and that a branch name has a lot to do with that.  But these aren't right!  A Git repository is, at its heart, a storage system for *commits*.  In other words, the unit of storage, in any repository, is the commit.

Now, it is true that *commits* contain files.  But the trick is that every commit contains *every* file—or more precisely, "every file it contains", although that sounds redundant.  You pick out one particular commit, such as `a123456`, and tell Git to *check out* that commit.  Git *removes other files* and then *extracts the files that are in that commit*.  You now have the files *from that commit*.

Again, the real focus here is, and stays on, the *commit*.  We always have to be concerned about the *commit*.  There's a problem here for us humans, though: commits have these big horrible random-looking [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) numbers like `a123456` or `f1dd1ee` or whatever, except that they're even bigger and longer and more random looking (my made-up ones, like `deadcab` and `feedc0ffee`, at least *resemble* words).  We call these things *hash IDs*, and each commit has a unique hash ID, which is the "true name" of the commit.

The hash IDs are impossible for humans to deal with correctly, though, so Git provides us names.  We start with *branch names* like `master` or `dev`.  These names let Git remember the *latest* hash ID for us.  But these names really just mean *get me the latest commit, whose hash ID is stored in that name*.  There are other kinds of names, but there is a special property of *branch* names, which we'll see soon.

#### What this means for you

What this means for you is that you *are not allowed to just create a new Git repository*.<sup>1</sup>  You must start by *copying the existing repository*.  The reason for this is that each new commit you make, in a Git repository, *connects back to some existing commits*.  So you have to *get* their commits first, so that you can connect your new commits to their old (existing) commits.  So this sequence doesn't quite work:

> 1. initialise the directory as a git repo (which I already did)
> 2. connect the initialised local repo somehow to the remote one.
> 3. Then create a branch based on the structure of the master branch of the remote repo (without losing any files on the local repo).
> 4. finally, push the code in the local repo to the newly created branch in the new repo.

It *can* be repaired in place, but it's tricky.  If you can, it's far easier to just start over.  I'll cover how to do that first.

---

<sup>1</sup>Welll, you are *allowed*, it's just going to become a problem if you do.

---

#### Starting over, part 1

Given that you have a directory (or folder) full of files and those are the files you want to have in your new commit on your new branch, we start by putting that aside.  We keep it ready, but we don't use it *yet*.

We now create a *new* folder (or directory), using `git clone`.  This is actually shorthand for doing five or six separate commands, which we will see in the "how to repair the existing setup" section, but for now, think of it this way: **`git clone` tells your Git software on your computer to call up some other computer somewhere, get some Git software on *their* computer to navigate to some Git repository, and have them pour out *all their commits*.  Your Git—your software on your computer—copies all the commits into a new repository on your computer.**  These commits form branches, whose latest commit is remembered—by the Git software on their computer—with *branch names*.  But when your Git—your software on your computer building your new repository—gets all the from their Git (their software reading their repository), your Git *doesn't* copy *any* of their branch names *as-is*.  Your Git takes their branch names and *changes* them.

Their Git repository has some URL, such as `ssh://git@gitlab.com/path/to/repo.git`.<sup>2</sup>  Your Git—by which I again mean "your software running on your computer, working on your local repository"—will store this URL under a name.  The default standard first name that `git clone` uses here is `origin`.  We call this name a *remote*, so this URL gets stored as the remote named `origin`.

This factors into the branch-name changes.  When your Git clones all the commits from their Git, your Git takes their *branch* names and changes them into *remote-tracking names*.  Their `master` becomes your `origin/master`; their `dev` becomes your `origin/dev`.  So, at this point in the cloning process, you have one *remote-tracking name* for each of their *branch* names.

If they have three branch names, they have three "most recent commit" hash IDs.  You now have three *remote-tracking names*, made by sticking `origin/` in front of each branch name.<sup>3</sup>

Now that you have *all of their commits* and *none of their branches*, `git clone` does its last special trick: it *creates one branch, and checks out the latest commit for that one branch*.  The branch it creates depends on the `-b` argument you give to `git clone`.  If you don't give `git clone` a `-b`, your Git asks their Git which *name* they recommend.  They'll generally recommend `master`, or GitHub now starts with `main` instead, and your Git will create that name, based on your `origin/master` or `origin/main`, which your Git made from their `master` or `main`.

The result of this complicated dance is that you now have *one* branch with the same name as one of their branches.  Your Git now uses `git checkout` or `git switch`<sup>4</sup> to check out the *latest commit on that branch, as stored in that branch name* (which your Git copied from your remote-tracking name from their branch name).

---

<sup>2</sup>Sometimes that's a local file path, in which case "their computer" is really your computer.  Sometimes that's a network drive, but if so, you will eventually discover that using network drives like this is error-prone: it's best to use an actual network *protocol* and call up the other computer on which the drive is local.  But that's a separate topic.

<sup>3</sup>Technically, the remote-tracking names are in a separate [namespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace) from the branch names.  This means even if you create a (local) branch name that is spelled `origin/something`, it's not a remote-tracking name.  *Git* will keep them straight—and by default, `git branch -a` will show the remote-tracking names in red and the branch names in other colors, so that you'll know which one is which—but don't do that; it makes things crazy for humans.

<sup>4</sup>The `git switch` command was new in Git 2.23.  It's the result of taking the old `git checkout`, which had two modes—one "safe" and one "unsafe"—and splitting it into two separate commands: `git switch`, which implements only the safe-mode check-out operations, and `git restore`, which implements the unsafe-mode check-out operations.  If you have 2.23 or later, it's a good idea to learn the new commands, so that you don't accidentally invoke the unsafe mode one when you think you're invoking the safe mode, but they're really almost the same.

---

#### Sidebar: commits vs working tree, and a brief look at the index

It's time for a short (well, short-ish) sidebar here, about *committed* files as stored in a Git commit, vs the files you work with.  Knowing this will explain a lot about Git that is otherwise mysterious.

*Everything in a Git commit is read-only.*  No part of any commit can ever be changed, once you (or whoever) has made the commit.  This way, each commit stores every file, in that particular version, *forever*—or at least, as long as the commit with that particular hash ID continues to exist.  (It's a bit hard to *remove* commits, and we won't cover that here.)

The files inside the commit are not stored like ordinary files on your computer.  Instead, they're in a special, read-only, Git-only, compressed and *de-duplicated* format.  This handles the fact that most commits mostly re-use most files from a previous commit.  Git actually stores the files' contents only *once*.  When you change the contents, Git will have to store a new copy, but if you're re-using an old file—or even changing a file *back*—Git will be able to re-use the earlier stored version.

But this means that the files inside a commit are literally only readable *by* Git itself, and writable by *nothing*.  These committed files, in other words, *cannot be used* for everyday work.  So they aren't.  Instead, when you *check out* a commit, Git *extracts the archived files from the commit*.

This extraction process is most of what `git checkout` or `git switch` is about.  Except for that initial `git clone`, we start with some commit that we have checked out now.  Then we pick a *different* commit to check out, and:

1. Git *removes* the files that came out of the *current* commit.
2. Git *fills in* the files that come out of the different commit, which then becomes the current commit.

This removing-and-filling-in happens in your *working tree*, which is simply the area in which you do your work.  These are the files you can *see* and *edit*.  But they are *not in Git*.  They were merely *extracted from* Git, from a commit.

Whenever Git does this extracting step, it keeps track of these files in something that Git calls, variously, the *index*, or the *staging area*, or—rarely these days—the *cache*.  These are three names for the same thing.  It's really crucially important—for instance, it's where Git gets the list of files to *remove* when you switch commits—but we won't cover it properly here at all.  Just remember that when you run `git add`, you're creating or updating a copy of a file in this index / staging-area.  When you run `git commit`, Git makes the *new commit snapshot* from the files that are in this staging area.

Hence, you *work* in your *working tree*, and *commit* from the index / staging-area.  Until you commit, though, your files aren't *in* Git.<sup>5</sup>  It's the *commits* that are the storage unit, that store the files.

When you *do* commit, Git will:

- package up all the files it has in its index / staging area, including any unmodified ones that came out of the *current* commit;
- add commit *metadata*, such as your name and email address;
- use the *current commit* hash ID as the *parent* of the new commit;
- write out the new commit, saving the packaged-up files permanently, or as long as this new commit continues to exist; and
- last, *write the new commit's hash ID*—obtained during the writing-out of the commit—*into the current branch name*.

This last step *adds the new commit* to the current branch.  **This is the special property of branch names.**  As we add new commits, Git "moves the branch name forward".  The new commit links back to what *was* the final commit before, and now the *new* commit *is* the final commit.

What this means is that if we draw out commits, using uppercase letters to stand in for the branch names, we get a picture that starts out like this:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <--master (HEAD)
```

where `H` is the *last* commit on `master`, that we checked out / extracted.  We then work on this commit for a while, in our working tree, and run `git add` and `git commit` to make a new commit `I`, which will point back to existing commit `H`.  Git will then write the *new* commit's *hash ID* `I` into the *name* `master`:

```
... <-F <-G <-H <-I   <--master (HEAD)
```

When we have more than one *branch name*, we usually start out with two names pointing to the *same commit*, like this:

```
...--G--H   <-- master (HEAD), new-branch
```

We then run `git checkout new-branch` or `git switch new-branch` to select the right *name:*

```
...--G--H   <-- master, new-branch (HEAD)
```

Note that Git cleverly notices that we're moving from commit `H` to commit `H`, which means we're not really changing *commits*.  Git therefore doesn't bother removing and replacing any files.<sup>6</sup>  Then we make our changes and add and commit:

```
...--G--H   <-- master
         \
          I   <-- new-branch (HEAD)
```

Note how new commit `I` still points back to commit `H`, as before.  But this time, we didn't *move* the name `master`.  We moved the name `new-branch`.

**This linkage from commit to commit is critical in Git.  Git doesn't work without it.**  So we have to start from the correct *starting* commit, when we make our new commit.

---

<sup>5</sup>Because of Git's internal storage format, `git add` does put a file's *content*—but not its *name*—into Git.  The content bytes can be recovered after particular accidents or disasters, for a while.  But if you don't commit them, the content bytes eventually get discarded, unless they're duplicates from some existing commit.

<sup>6</sup>This optimization lets us *create and switch to* a new branch name *after* we've started working, in case we forgot to do that in advance.

---

#### Starting over, part 2: the commands you'd use

1. `git clone url`: this will copy a Git repository—or rather, its commits—to your computer and get you a new *working tree* in the new checkout.  Then `cd` (or whatever your change-working-directory command is) into the new clone.
2. `git checkout dev`, if necessary (or add `-b dev` to the clone command above).  Remember, you're picking the *desired starting commit* here, via a branch name.  If you prefer the new `git switch`, run `git switch dev` (or, again, use the `-b` option during the clone command in step 1).
3. `git checkout -b new_dev_branch`, to create the *new* branch name and switch to it.  With `git switch`, the `-b` changes to `-c` (create): `git switch -c new_dev_branch`.  There's no rhyme or reason to the `-b` vs `-c` here; you just have to memorize it.
4. Run whatever your local command is to copy each file *from* the place where you have them now, to the working tree here.  Or, consider running `git rm -r .`, to remove all files from your working tree here, then copying all the files from the other location.<sup>7</sup>
5. `git add .` or `git add` for each new file; `git rm` for any file you want removed.  This updates Git's index AKA staging area, so that you are ready to commit.
6. `git commit`, to make a new commit and update the name `new_dev_branch`.
7. `git push origin new_dev_branch`: this has your Git call up their Git, using the URL stored under the name `origin`.  Your Git hands to their Git any new commits you have, that they don't, that they need: i.e., the commit you made in step 6.  Then, having given them this new commit (and any all-new files in it—the de-duplication means you don't have to give them any *old* files that still match), your Git asks their Git to create the new-to-them branch name `new_dev_branch`.  Since this name *is* new to them, you'll be allowed to do this, assuming you are allowed to create new names.  Their name `new_dev_branch` will now remember the same "last" commit that your name `new_dev_branch` remembers, and your Git will create `origin/new_dev_branch` to remember that their Git remembers this commit as their branch named `new_dev_branch`.

   **This command is likely to fail at the moment, so you will need to pick a different branch name, or else first *delete* the `new_dev_branch` name in the remote, or use force-push.**  See the section on recovering from what you've done so far, below.
8. `git branch --set-upstream-to origin/new_dev_branch`: this has your Git set the *upstream* setting of your existing branch, `new_dev_branch`, to be your `origin/new_dev_branch`, which is your Git's memory of their branch name `new_dev_branch`.

You only have to do step 8 *once:* each of your branch names, in your Git repository, can remember exactly one *upstream*.  Remembering an upstream is optional, but gives you some nice features.

You can make step 7, the `git push` operation, do step 8 for you by using `git push -u origin new_dev_branch`.  This is just a convenience short-cut.  It will run step 8 if and only if the `git push` part succeeds.  Since you only have to set the upstream whenever you want it to *change*, you only need the `-u` option once.

---

<sup>7</sup>If you use some sort of en-masse file move operation, be careful: the *Git repository* itself is stored in the `.git` directory (or folder) at the top of your working tree.  This is where Git keeps all its own files, and is where the actual repository is.  Your working tree is *yours*, and you can do whatever you like with it, as long as you keep in mind that some Git commands, like `git restore` or `git reset --hard`, will scribble on your working tree files.  But Git's repository files are precious to Git, and if you mess with the wrong one, Git will be sad<sup>8</sup> and stop working.

<sup>8</sup>Don't anthropomorphize computers, they hate that!

---

#### You already ran `git init` and it didn't do what you wanted.  Here's how to recover.

Here, from your question, is what you ran.  I've numbered them so that we can refer to them below.

> 1. `cd my-project`
> 2. `git init`
> 3. `git fetch`
> 4. `git checkout -b new_dev_branch`
> 5. `git add .`
> 6. `git commit -m "first trial"`
> 7. `git remote add origin path/to/remote/gitlab/my-project.git`
> 8. `git push -u origin new_dev_branch`

Step 1 is pretty simple.  In step 2, Git told you:

```
Initialized empty Git repository in .../my-project/.git/
```

If it said instead that it *re-initialized* an *existing* Git repository, stop here!  This is only for the *new repository* case.

Step 3 will just silently do nothing, because there is *no remote to fetch from*.  So you still have an empty repository:

```
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in ...
$ git fetch
$
```

I'm not sure why Git doesn't *complain* here; it really should.

An *empty* Git repository has no commits and no branches.  While it has no branches, you're still *on* some branch: you are just on a branch that *does not exist*.  It's a peculiar state of affairs, but Git fixes it up when you create your first commit.  So, we move on to step 4, which changes the name of the branch that you are on—that doesn't exist—from `master` to `new_dev_branch`:

```
$ git checkout -b new_dev_branch
Switched to a new branch 'new_dev_branch'
```

Step 5 adds all the files in the current directory to Git's index / staging-area, so that they are ready to be committed.  This produces no output as long as it works.  Step 6 then turns all of these files, plus the added metadata, into the *first* commit in this new repository.  The repository is no longer empty, so now the branch name can exist.  The branch name springs into existence, pointing to this one commit.  This commit can't point back to any earlier commit, so it just doesn't.  Git calls this a *root commit:*

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "first trial"
[new_dev_branch (root-commit) f342d15] first trial
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 README
```

In my case I had only the one file, `README`, that I added.  Note the `(root-commit)`; the number here, `f342d15`, is unique, so yours will be different; the current branch name is `new_dev_branch` and that branch now exists.

Your step 7 *created a remote* named `origin`, storing the URL (`path/to/remote/gitlab/my-project.git`).  This enables the `git push` command to run.  Your step 8 sent your new *root* commit and created a branch named `new_dev_branch`.  Since your root commit has no *parent* commit, it does not link into the history of existing commits.

Given that you don't really want the other Git repository to use this commit as `new_dev_branch`, you should probably first *delete* `new_dev_branch` from the repository over at `origin`:

```
git push --delete origin new_dev_branch
```

This has your Git call up their Git and ask them to delete their branch named `new_dev_branch`.

Let's rename the (local) branch, too, to `error`, so that we have it out of the way:

```
$ git branch -m error
$ git branch
* error
```

Next, we need to obtain, from the other Git repository, *all of their commits*.  That's easy to do: just run `git fetch` now!  I haven't set up another repository so I won't show any output here:

```
git fetch
```

Your Git will call up their Git, have them list out all their branch names and corresponding commit hash IDs, and use those to obtain, from their Git, *all* their commits, and create, in your own local repository, remote-tracking names for each of their branch names.  When this completes, run `git branch -a` or `git branch -r` to see all these names.

(Note: for no apparent reason, `git branch -r` lists the remote-tracking names as `origin/master`, `origin/dev`, and so on, but `git branch -a` lists them as `remotes/origin/master`, `remotes/origin/dev`, and so on.  This has to do with the name-spaces I mentioned earlier.  There's still no reason for `git branch -a` to do this, though.)

We now want to check out some existing commit, as found via some remote-tracking name.  This will remove from your working tree all the files you've committed into your root commit, on your branch currently named `error`.  That's OK because they are all safely stored in that *commit*.

Note that we don't have a branch named `dev`, nor one named `master`.  And yet, we can run:

```
git checkout dev      # or git switch dev
```

or the same with `master`.  This invokes what Git calls *DWIM mode*, or—in recent versions of `git checkout` and `git switch`—the `--guess` mode.  This mode is enabled by default; using `--no-guess` turns it off.

What this mode *does* is simple-ish: if there is no *branch* with the name we give, before saying something like `error: no such branch: dev`, Git will poke around in our *remote-tracking names*.  If there's one that sufficiently *resembles* the name we asked for, Git will act as though we ran:

```
git checkout -b dev origin/dev
```

or:

```
git switch -c dev origin/dev
```

That is, Git will *create* our `dev` based on our `origin/dev` that's based on `origin`'s `dev`.  This is the same trick that `git clone` pulls off during the initial clone: if *they* have a `dev`, we probably want *our* `dev` to match.  That's the guess, or the "do what I mean": DWIM.

You can just be explicit and run:

```
git checkout -t origin/dev
```

or:

```
git switch -t origin/dev
```

The `-t` or `--track` option (either spelling is allowed) means *here's the remote-tracking name; create a branch based on that name, and set the upstream of the new branch*.  The upstream setting happens when the DWIM / `--guess` code does its thing too, so `-t` is just an explicit variant.<sup>9</sup>

**Now that we have a `dev`, and its files are checked out—I'm assuming that you'd like your `new_dev_branch` to start from *this* commit—*now* we're ready to make a *new* commit from all the files that are in your root commit on branch `error`.**  Things get a little tricky here.

What we need to do now is:

- replace all the files in our working tree with those from `error`;
- replace all the files in Git's index with those from `error`; and
- commit.

There is a simple and straightforward way to do this:

```
git rm -r .
git checkout error -- .
git commit
```

This starts by removing all files from both Git's index and our working tree.  We only *have* to do this if there are some files in the *current commit* that won't be in the *new* commit.

We then use the "dangerous" mode of `git checkout` to wipe out all our files.  This isn't really dangerous at this point, since already did that.  We *replace* these files with those from the commit named by branch `error`.  The `-- .` tells `git checkout` *all files in the specified commit*, just as the `git rm -r .` told Git *all files that are in your index*.

There are two ways to avoid the `git rm -r` step.  One of them is rather deeply magical as it uses one of Git's *plumbing commands*.  We simply run:

```
git read-tree -m -u error
```

I don't really like this one because it's overly magic.  Instead, we can use:

```
git restore -s error -SW -- .
```

which is more explicit: we ask `git restore` to restore all the files to exactly the way they look in commit `error`, removing any files that *aren't* in that commit.  This is different from `git checkout error -- .`, which won't *remove* files that aren't in that commit.<sup>10</sup>  The `-SW` options tell Git to write both the index and the working tree.

Having used `git restore` or `git read-tree`, or the two-command remove-and-replace `git rm` and `git checkout` sequence, to fix up our index and working tree, we now simply run `git commit`.  This makes a new commit, on the current branch, as usual.  The files *in* this new commit exactly match the files in the (lone, root) commit on branch `error`.

We can now `git push -u origin new_dev_branch` to (re-)create the `new_dev_branch` branch over on `origin`.  It contains this commit *and* all the earlier commits, so it is the desired history.

There's one last trick we can use to make this shorter.  We ran:

```
git checkout dev
```

to create `dev` from `origin/dev`, then:

```
git checkout -b new_dev_branch
```

to create `new_dev_branch` with the same commit hash ID, and switch to `new_dev_branch`, with no upstream set for `new_dev_branch`.  But we can *combine* these at the cost of not creating a local `dev` branch in the first place—a trivial cost since we can always create it *later*.  All we need to do is:

- create `new_dev_branch`, pointing to the right commit
- but with no upstream set

and to do that, we can use:

```
git checkout -b new_dev_branch --no-track origin/dev
```

The `--no-track` keeps Git from setting `origin/dev` as the upstream.  Actually *setting* that would be mostly harmless (we'll replace it with `git push -u`), but it's perhaps nicer and safer to avoid it.  Of course, if you have `git restore`, you also have `git switch` and we probably should use that, so we want:

```
git switch -c new_dev_branch --no-track origin/dev
```

here, as our shortcut.

---

<sup>9</sup>The profusion of ways to do this is mostly historical accident.  However, there's a bit of a problem if you have *two or more* remotes, all of which have a `dev`.  Suppose you have `r1/dev` and `r2/dev` and you run `git checkout dev` while you don't have a `dev`.  Which remote-tracking name, `r1/dev` or `r2/dev`, should Git use?  Using `git checkout -t r2/dev` tells Git which one to use, so the `-t` option works when the DWIM mode doesn't.

<sup>10</sup>Internally, Git calls this `--overlay` or `--no-overlay`.  In older versions of Git, `git checkout` always runs in `--overlay` mode, and `git restore` always runs in `--no-overlay` mode.  In modern Git these options are exposed.  See [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore) for further details.

---

#### More about `git clone`

This wouldn't be complete without expanding out `git clone` to its constituent parts.  You can replicate what `git clone` does using six commands, one of them a plain shell (or CLI) command and the remainder Git commands run in the new directory:

1. `mkdir clone && cd clone`, or your CLI equivalent: make the new directory.
2. `git init`: create an empty Git repository here.
3. `git remote add origin url`: add a remote named `origin` to store the given URL.  Use some other name if you gave the `-o` option.
4. Any `git config` commands you need, if you gave `-c` options to `git clone`, or options like `--single-branch` (though you can put the single-branch-ness in the `git remote add` instead if you prefer).
5. `git fetch` or `git fetch remote` (I'm not sure if you have to spell out the remote name if it's not `origin`, but you might).
6. `git checkout branch`: create the branch you chose with `-b`, or the recommended branch (learning the recommendation is tricky but you can probably assume `main` or `master` in most cases).  If you used `-n`, skip this step.

Running `git clone` just does these six steps, with a bit of fanciness: it discovers the recommended branch name; it figures out the name of the directory to make based on the URL, if you don't point it to some existing empty directory; and it will remove the partially-built clone if something goes wrong.  But it's really just hiding the fact that it runs `git fetch` and `git checkout` for you.

Comment: thanks a lot, @torek for this detailed and helpful reply. I was worried that the method I used will do harm in the future. also, I found a folder named `my-project.git` among the newly pushed branch folders with some other files like `head` etc. 

I would like to learn more about Git and versioning control. I would be grateful if you could recommend me some useful resources. I know if should practise as well but it is better to build a solid understanding beyond using the commands.

Comment: There is at present only one *book* I'd recommend about Git, which is the free [Pro Git 2](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) book. I think it might be possible to have a better book, but other books are mostly badly out of date at this point; this one gets updated. Once you're used to some of the Git basics, I also recommend reading through [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/).

Answer (score 1):

You can pull remote `master` branch into your `new_dev_branch` branch:

```
$ git checkout new_dev_branch
$ git pull origin master
```

Now, check if all is ok then push to remote:

```
$ git push origin new_dev_branch
```

---

Another way you can do the following -

Checkout to the `new_dev_branch` branch and copy the latest commit hash:

```
$ git checkout new_dev_branch
$ git log
# copy the latest commit_hash
```

Create a new branch (e.g. *new_dev_branch_2*) from `remote's master` branch. Now, take (cherry pick) your commit:

```
$ git checkout -b new_dev_branch_2 origin/master
$ git cherry-pick <commit_hash>
```

Now, check if all is ok then push the `new_dev_branch_2` branch to remote.

```
$ git push origin new_dev_branch_2
```